# Visual studio 2015 with Resharper Unresponsive

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2015

did any of you encountered problems with this setup ? I'm using the latest version of Resharper (9.2) and just installed VS2015. Problem is that most of the time it gets unresponsive for shord periods of time. This happens quite often.

I don't have tools for node installed (I've read that this may cause some problems.)

Comment: [Go through this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Ultimate+Guide+to+Speeding+Up+ReSharper+%28and+Visual+Studio%29) if you haven't already.  Also, I saw sluggishness until I upgraded the VS solution I was working with from 2010 to 2015.  Not sure if that had anything to do with it or applies in your case, but it helped me almost immediately.

Comment: most of these things are already set, and others seem to be just to tell you to turn off functionality that was normally fast in VS without resharper, not sure why it is so slow for me

Comment: I have where VS will freeze for about 5-10 seconds at a time, seeming to have something to do with resharper's intellisense, but I'm not sure. It happens in very specific circumstances, almost always when I'm writing properties and fields, or sometimes when writing parameter lists (especially vertically stacked ones). It never happens when I'm writing code in a method. (This is with VS2013, though.)

Comment: I guess all the problems might have come from computer setup (no ssd). Since my post I was using 2 different computers with SSD drives and the problems don't occure.